# Using namespace for classes

Tags: php, class, namespaces

Im trying to run this code :

```
$spaceMarine = new \ Imperium \ Soldier (" Gessart ");
$chaosSpaceMarine = new \ Chaos \ Soldier (" Ruphen ");
echo $spaceMarine . "\n";
echo $chaosSpaceMarine . "\n";
$spaceMarine -> doDamage ( $chaosSpaceMarine );
echo $spaceMarine . "\n";
echo $chaosSpaceMarine . "\n";
// Has to display :
Gessart the Imperium Space Marine : 50 HP.
Ruphen the Chaos Space Marine : 70 HP.
Gessart the Imperium Space Marine : 50 HP.
Ruphen the Chaos Space Marine : 58 HP.
```

I was wondering if using namespace absolutely requires that i make the 2 Soldier classes in different files ?  because i did it all in the same page :

```
namespace Imperium;



class Soldier
{
private $_hp;
private $_attack;
private $_name;


function __construct($name, $hp = 50, $attack = 12)
{
    $this->_name = $name;
    $this->_hp = $hp;
    $this->_attack = $attack;
}
public function getHP()
{
    return $this->_hp;
}

public function setHP($hp)
{
    $this->_hp = $hp;
}

public function getAttack()
{
    return $this->_attack;
}
public function setAttack($attack)
{
    $this->_attack = $attack;
}

public function doDamage($obj)
{

    $obj = $this->_hp - $this->_attack;
}
public function __toString()
{
    echo "$this->_name the Imperium Space Marine : $this->_hp";
}
}


namespace Chaos;

class Soldier
{

function __construct($name, $hp = 70, $attack = 12)
{
    $this->_name = $name;
    $this->_hp = $hp;
    $this->_attack = $attack;
}

public function getHP()
{
    return $this->_hp;
}

public function setHP($hp)
{
    $this->_hp = $hp;
}

public function getAttack()
{
    return $this->_attack;
}
public function setAttack($attack)
{
    $this->_attack = $attack;
}

public function doDamage($obj)
{

    $obj = $this->_hp - $this->_attack;
}

public function __toString()
{
    echo "$this->_name __NAMESPACE__ Space Marine : $this->_hp";
}
}

use Imperium;
use Chaos;

$spaceMarine = new \Imperium\Soldier ("Gessart");
$chaosSpaceMarine = new \Chaos\Soldier ("Ruphen");
echo $spaceMarine . "\n";
echo $chaosSpaceMarine . "\n";
$spaceMarine -> doDamage ( $chaosSpaceMarine );
echo $spaceMarine . "\n";
echo $chaosSpaceMarine . "\n";
```

is there a way to do it all in the same page ? the following code doesnt work it says :

> Catchable fatal error: Method Imperium\Soldier::__toString() must
>   return a string value

Im not sure to totally understand namespaces..

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: The error has nothing to do with namespace. `__toString` must __return__ the string, not print it.

Comment: You may want to look at inheritance, looks like you are building two completely new classes, one in each of the namespaces - I would have thought that these were very similar classes and perhaps should have a base class called Soldier and each of these would extend that and add their own details.

Comment: Yes i know what you mean but i already know how inherence works i just wanted to get more familliar with the namespacing way

Comment: That last edit messed up your post pretty bad :)

Comment: @zeea If the code is a confidential exercise then the solution is __not to post it here__. The solution isn't to ask the question, get an answer and then edit it to remove the code. That's abusing everyone else's time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Namespacing does not *require* that you define classes in different files. However, you should. It is considered a best practice, and if you do so, you can use [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading.

Regarding the error, that's a simple fix -- just `return` the string instead of echoing it:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return "$this->_name the Imperium Space Marine : $this->_hp";
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! now i got this error :  Fatal error: Cannot declare class Chaos\Soldier, because the name is already in use in 'dir..'